# change aspect ratio of a UIVIew in UIViewController from subview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a UIView in a UIViewController. There are three UIView classes from which I am changing the aspect ratio of UIView in controller. Please let me know how can I change the aspect ratio of UIView in controller from three uiview classes. I am getting problem in iOS 12.0 while it works in iOS 11.0. Here is how I am changin the aspect ratio:

```
   _ =  (UIApplication.visibleNavigationController.visibleViewController as! EditImageControl).editImageContainer.addConstraintForAspectRatio(21/22)
    (UIApplication.visibleNavigationController.visibleViewController as! EditImageControl).editImageContainer.layoutSubviews()
     print("horizontal.. ")
```

Comment: "I am getting problem in xcode 10 while it works in xcode 9.4" <--- what problem?

Comment: How can I change the aspect ratio of a UIView in controller from three UIView classes.

Comment: No, you mentioned that what you're doing works in Xcode 9.4 but not in Xcode 10. What's the problem you get in Xocde 10?

Comment: You still didn't mention the problem you're having in iOS 12.0.